# How to know if I am blocked in Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I blocked some programmer on Gmail chat and after two weeks I unblocked him. Now instead of the status circle I don't see anything (and that after I sent him some mail, thus I expected to see his online status).

[image]

Does it say that he blocked me too? Is there a way to know if someone blocked me on Gmail chat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIDGIN

Right-click on the offline user, select "Get Info"

If he is offline and has not blocked you, the information window displays the user name and other profile information he has made public.

If the Information window is blank, the user has blocked you.

Comment: there is no right click actions in gmail...Do i miss something? I have a popups only

Comment: i said PIDGIN; a universal chat program

Comment: I am looking for a way without installation additional soft actually, but thank you for the answer. I upvote it as an option.